# Facebook memorialization information within the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm currently building a Social Media Dashboard where I'm doing a huge amount of data analysis for various social media providers. I'm now at the stage of doing analysis for a user's Facebook friends. One thing I'd like to do is analyse how many of a user's friends has passed (meaning their account has become a memorialized account). Does the Facebook Graph API offer any information about this?

I've done a fair amount of research on this topic, but I could only find information regarding the process of declaring an account memorialized:

From Facebook FAQ:

> **How do I report a deceased user or an account that needs to be
>   memorialized and deactivated or
>   deleted?**
>
> Memorializing the account:
>
> Please report [this information here](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=deceased) so
>   that we can memorialize this person’s
>   account. Memorializing the account
>   restricts profile access to confirmed
>   friends only. Please note that in
>   order to protect the privacy of the
>   deceased user, we cannot provide login
>   information for the account to anyone.
>   We do honor requests from close family
>   members to close the account
>   completely.
>
> Removing the account:
>
> Immediate family
>   members may request the removal of a
>   loved one’s account. This will
>   completely remove the account from
>   Facebook so that no one can view it.
>   We will not restore the account or
>   provide information on its content
>   unless required by law. If you are
>   requesting a removal and are not an
>   immediate family member of the
>   deceased, your request will not be
>   processed, but the account will be
>   memorialized.
>
> To make a request to memorialize or
>   remove a profile, please do so [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=deceased).
>   If you have a special request
>   regarding a deceased user's account,
>   please use this form. Please note that
>   [this form](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=memorialize_special_requests) is only to be used for
>   accounts that have already been
>   memorialized.

Does anyone know if Facebook will ever add support for this within their API? A field called `is_memorialized` from a Graph API profile response would be enough for my needs at the moment.

Should I contact Facebook about this?